# Google Cloud Function python won't deploy cryptic error

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a google cloud function that I have deployed before. I literally deployed this same function with no code changes several days ago. However, when I deploy now I get the following message

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: Build error details not available

The logs in the cloud don't give an indication of what the problem might be. I **can** deploy a simple do nothing test function. I suspect the issue may have something to do with my requirements.txt file because I even commented out all the code in my function and it would not deploy. So the only difference between my test function and my real function at that point is the requirements.txt.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Or you have specified an invalid or incorrect entry point (starting function name).

Comment: Can you share the `requirements.txt ` file in the description? It will be easier to try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for that idea. I am using the default main.py and I am sure that the function name I am using in the gcloud command is in the file.

Comment: I created a new folder and symlinked the various files into it and tried deploying from there. That worked surprisingly. So what is the difference between the two folders? My original, "real" folder has a .gcloudignore file that gcloud created because there is a git repo in there. 

So the fact that there is a .git folder and/or .gcloudignore file seems to be breaking the deploy. At least I have a temporary work around.

Comment: Go to the Google Cloud Console -> Cloud Functions. Click on the "Source" tab. This will show you the deployment files. What is different?

Comment: @JohnHanley Will that work? As the deployment actually fails, so the function does not get updated in the cloud. There is an indication that the deployment failed, but no real information about it.

Comment: Did you check? I don't know what the problem is, so I don't know what the console will show you.

Comment: Yeah, I did check that (sorry I wrote my response in a weird tense). Seems to have something to do with the .gcloudignore file. gcloud creates that file if there is git repo in the folder or maybe if there is a python virtual environment. Again, as a work around I created a subfolder and symlinked the files form the parent folder. I suppose it would also work to just have the "source" In a subfolder so any git repo or venv is not in the upload folder. I think I will give that a shot.

Comment: I have been able to re deploy a Cloud Function with the same name but changing the requirements.txt with no issue at all. Also I did it in a folder with a .gitignore file and the previous .gcloudignore file created in the previous deployment. As @AndreiCusnir already suggested, would be cool to see the requirements.txt to see where the error may be coming from. Maybe using the --source flag may be helpful as gcloud command is getting confused on which files to use for the deploy